# How to read numbers from flash application?

Tags: flash

I have a flash game in which from time to time show some numbers. And I want to read this numbers. Its are always white on red background. Any ideas how to optimal read numbers to int?
At the moment I have only idea that somehow read pixels? Please about some ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by you need to read these numbers? You want the value within your flash code? You want an external program to do some OCR or something?

Comment: I need make program which will be saving these numbers to some text file. So I need some idea that read this numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the textbox's value in actionscript like so:

```
myTextBox.text
```

And then you can get actionscript to create an xml file with the information.

Comment: Can you explain me more your idea?

Comment: To my knowledge, Actionscript 3.0 is able to generate xml files. So just grab the textbox data with `.text` and then export an xml file with the value you want.